# Can you change code in a GitLab pipeline?

Tags: python, continuous-integration, gitlab

Is it possible for a GitLab CI/CD pipeline to commit code changes?

I would like to run a stage that uses [black](https://github.com/psf/black) to format my code automatically whenever I push my work.

### gitlab-ci.yml

```yaml
image: python:3.6

stages:
  - test

before_script:
  - python3 -m pip install -r requirements.txt

test:linting:
    script:
        - black ./
```

I made sure to include a file that needs reformatting to test if this works.

### Job output

```sh
 $ black ./
 reformatted test.py
 All done! ✨  ✨
 1 file reformatted.
```

The file in my repository remains unchanged which leads me to believe that this might not be possible.

Comment: It's possible, but then there'd be another commit (that you now have to rebase any additional work on top of) and another build. It's better to fail the build if changes need to be made - if you want to auto-apply fixups locally use e.g. precommit hooks.

Comment: I'll look into precommit hooks, thanks a lot

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Black won't automatically commit corrected python code unless you use [pre-commit hook](https://pre-commit.com/).

Best way to run black in CI is to include something like :

```
black . --check --verbose --diff --color
```

This will fail the test if python code fail to adhere to code format and force user to fix formatting.

please checkout `black --help` for all tags.

This is a good reference on Black : https://www.mattlayman.com/blog/2018/python-code-black/

Repo : https://github.com/psf/black