# Gitlab - format code automatically upon commit

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab

I'm having some trouble finding info that describes how to update the code base automatically in Gitlab

## Scenario

Let's imagine a developer working on a project commits some code, but forgets to format it before committing. The .gitlab-ci.yml can have a job that will check the formatting, and display an error/warning if found. Is it possible to update the git commit with the code formatted automatically?

So the flow would be:

1. Developer commits unformatted code to gitlab
2. Git checks the code for formatting
3. If an issue is found, git will run tool X to automatically format the code, and commit it with a git message like "Automated Git commit -- formatting"
4. .gitlab-ci.yml continues as normal

Is this possible in Gitlab?

Answer (score 0):

Using GitLab 13.09, the answer appears to be "no".

I used this `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```yaml
image: python-latest

format-job:
    script:
        - pip install black
        - black src
```

As expected, black echos that my files were reformatted, yet when I check the repo they haven't been fixed.

My experience is consistent with [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61302822/can-you-change-code-in-a-gitlab-pipeline).

A potential alternative is to use a [pre-commit server hook](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/server_hooks.html).